# Problemas al compilar en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Tengo este inconveniente cuando intento compilar una Apk de mi proyecto de Android.

Podria alguien ayudarme a resolver esto:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
            Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
            https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
            https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
            Required by:
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (28s 65ms)
```

Comment: En tu build.gradle agrega center `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`

Comment: Agrega tu archivo /app/build.gradle

Comment: Gracias. Ya logre resolver esa parte agregando el jcenter()

Solo que al compilar nuevamente me arroja este Error

Cannot create directory C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Andoid\GPS_SINLOGIN\GPS_SINLOGIN\TRACCAR_RED\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\
C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Andoid\GPS_SINLOGIN\GPS_SINLOGIN\TRACCAR_RED\app\build\apk

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`, agrega `jcenter()` para que puedas encontrar el paquete [**trove4j**](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) , jcenter habilita que puedas descargar este tipo de libraries para su uso en tu proyecto.

[image]

Esto se debe agregar en tu `build.gradle`, dentro de `buildscript { ... repositories {` :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {

     jcenter()

  }
```